# Using wmi to get the VSS shadow copy's dos path

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi, volume-shadow-service

`vssadmin list shadows` show the dos path of every volume copy, in the following form:

```
\\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy4
```

Is there a way to do this using wmi?

I'ved looked through [`Win32_ShadowCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#methods) and experimented with it a bit, but couldn't find anything that gives the dos path. The other classes on msdn don't seem to have it either, I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DeviceObject` field provides this path in the `Win32_ShadowCopy` class.

The latter can be obtained as usual, e.g. using the query `SELECT * FROM Win32_ShadowCopy`.

*Sidenote*: I was searching for `dos` in the page which didn't exist, found it after re-reading the (rather long) doc page a couple more times.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren I've added more info, anything else you looking for to make this more complete?

Comment: No this looks a lot better!